# Filtering with Django-Taggit: Is it possible to filter for model entries that include all tags?

Tags: django, django-models, django-taggit

The code:

```
Food.objects.filter(tags__name__in=["Tag 1","Tag 2","Tag 3"]).distinct()
```

More precisely, if I want to filter for Food(s) where Food(s) has at least all three tags (not just one or two of the three, but could have more than the three), is there a modification to the filter provided in docs that achieves this result?

http://django-taggit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
tag_list = ["Tag 1","Tag 2","Tag 3"]
```

one way is to use multiple filters in a chained manner. Like this

```
Food.objects.filter(tags__name=tag_list[0]).filter(tags__name=tag_list[1]).filter(tags__name=tag_list[3]).distinct()
```

another way is to use [annotation approach](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/django-users/X9TCSrBn57Y/II8SjO6sWQYJ)

```
Food.objects.filter(tags__name__in=tag_list).annotate(num_tags=Count('tags')).filter(num_tags__gte=len(tag_list)).distinct()
```

Comment: Thanks for responding. I just tried the "multiple filters in a chained manner" approach and got a ValueError "invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Tag 1'" ... Any thoughts on what I might be doing incorrectly?

Comment: Thank you! Worked perfectly.

Comment: @Peter Please accept this as the correct answer. It'll help others as well